# What is the use of Flush Event in Multi-site manager?

Tags: multisite

I want to understand the multi-site manager Flush event.

Because of flush event triggered every time after successful creation of site, IIS reset's which makes the site outage and not able to perform any operation.

Is this really needed or the FLUSH operation can be postponed during deployment activity?

Comment: What is your Sitecore Version?

Comment: I'm using sitecore 8.1

Comment: Can you use the version 4.0 of the multisite manager. I see it allows you to choose when to restart the app pool as they changed it to an event

Comment: Thanks for the response. If we hold the FLUSH operation will it cause any problem?

Comment: The new site may not be available. Because it will need to update the host file or web.config

Comment: I have converted the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the version 4.0 of the Multiple Site Manager which is compatible with Sitecore 8.1.

The module no longer uses the publish end pipelines to trigger site flush. Instead, there is new event `multisitesmanager:flush:remote` to do the job.

So, you can decide when you want to use the flush operation. If you check the checkboxes after creating a site, it is at this moment that the flush operation will trigger.

[image]

Note that you need to flush the changes because if you have added a new hostName updated target host name select the check boxes to restart servers. This is required to clear out linkbuilder’s cache (LinkBuilder class is used by sitecore to build site links).

More information can be found [here](http://blog.alpha-solutions.us/2015/06/multiple-site-manager-4-0/).